# JUnit Test (Spring MVC Controller) возвращает не правильное значение

Tags: юнит-тесты, junit

Когда делаю тест контроллера, возвращает ошибку:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'placeTypesList'
>   Expected: a collection with size <2>
>      but: collection size was <0>

Хотя все вроде написано правильно. Перепробовал уже несколько вариантов как решить этот вопрос, пробовал по разному мокать сервис, но всегда одно и тоже.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:unit-test-context/test-context.xml",
    "classpath:unit-test-context/servlet-context.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PlaceTypeControllerTest {
    MockMvc mockMvc;
    @InjectMocks
    PlaceTypeController placeTypeController;

    @Mock
    View mockView;

    @Mock
    PlaceTypeService placeTypeService;

    @Autowired
    FileService fileService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.reset(placeTypeService);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

    }

    @Test
    public void getAllPlaceTypesTest() throws Exception {

        List<PlaceType> list = new ArrayList<PlaceType>();
        list.add(new PlaceType());
        list.add(new PlaceType());

        when(placeTypeService.getAllPlaceType()).thenReturn(list);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/placelist")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("placeTypeList"))
                .andExpect(model().attributeExists("placeTypesList"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("placeTypesList", hasSize(2)));

    }
}
```

вот сам метод, который тестится:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/placelist")
public ModelAndView getPlaceTypesList(Model model){

    List<PlaceType> placeTypeList = placeTypeService.getAllPlaceType();
    model.addAttribute("placeTypesList", placeTypeList);
    return new ModelAndView("placeTypeList");
}
```